# query_posts Exclude Directory, next_posts_link not work

Tags: wordpress

Can anybody look at the following codes? After I excluded the category 15, the next_posts_link does not work, nor does the page navigation plugin. When I click the page 2, 3,4, it only display the posts in page 1.

```
<?php query_posts('cat=-15'); ?>

    <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
           ...  ....
         <?php endwhile; else: ?>
        <?php next_posts_link() ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

How about...

```
<?php query_posts('cat=-15'); ?>

    <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
           ...  ....
    <?php endwhile; ?>

  <?php next_posts_link() ?>        

<?php endif; ?>
```

??

Comment: Mild, sorry, my error. The next_posts_link() is before endif. I updated code

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this:

```
<?php query_posts(array( 'cat' => -15, 'paged' => get_query_var('paged') ) ); ?>
```

This should work.